# Find the dirty(edited) cell/cells from excel sheet using Excel JavaScript API

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

I am using office 365 and Excel online (Build 16.0.9403.1875).

and I am creating Microsoft Excel online Add-ins, using [Excel javascript API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheet).

How to find the dirty cell/cells from excel sheet **using Excel Javascript API**.

If a cell is edited by value / formula / format, that became dirty. So I need to find, what are all the cells are dirty(edited) from range of cells.

For Reference, please find `calculate` method in this [link](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheet).

Comment: What on earth is a "dirty cell"? I'm afraid to even google that at work.

Comment: If a cell is edited by value or format, that became dirty. So I need to find, what are all the cells are dirty(edited) from range of cells.

Comment: A safer google from work: "IsDirty"  as that's the proper syntax in most coding standards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Excel JavaScript API that will return the dirty cells, but it's a good idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: Thanks, Will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since Excel doesn't natively have a dirty flag, you'll need to produce one via one of two methods:

Catch the cell edit event and record a list of edited cells that are dirty.

```
Dim Dirty As New Collection

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = Sh
    Dirty.Add (sheet.Name + "!" + Target.Address)
End Sub
```

OR

When you need the dirty flag, open the saved copy behind the scenes and compare the two to see what has changed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just have an option to use only JavaScript. The second option is possible, but have to check all (value / formula / any format) for each cell to decide.

Comment: Sorry, missed the Javascript API note.  Can you catch the sheet/workbook events there?

Comment: From the link you provided in the question, looks like you do have access to the onChanged event.

Comment: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheetchangedeventargs  The syntax will be different in Java, but the algorithm provided should work.  You might store a more complex object with the address and worksheet id rather than the concatenated string address.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
- In what way this event object will help us to find the dirty cell?.
- Event Object properties are very minimal and those properties of no use on my context.
- as you mentioned, I collect cell information which are complex object and i should find the pristine cell(untouched cell), so i will just ignore it to reduce my object(data) size.

Comment: If the event is fired, than the address within the event details is a cell becoming dirty.  Keep a list of those addresses and you'll know all dirty cells.

Comment: If you only care about specific cells and don't want to have a list of all dirty cells, you could use  https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/bindingdatachangedeventargs on the range object for that cell.

Comment: Fine, What happens, if i copy and  paste content from another excel sheet? How do i find and gather list of dirty and pristine(pure,untouched) cells?

Comment: For Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753324/how-to-identify-the-changed-cell-in-office-js-api-bindingdatachanged-event